# Generating 3D coordinates using let command

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

I want to create a tikz figure with 3d coordinates. I wanted to use 3D coordinates to make life easier, but when I implemented the cross-product using the let command, an error "Dimension too large. ...(X3) in coordinate (X) at (\x1, \x2, \x3);" is thrown. I found out that using three coordinates is the problem, so if I use just (\x1, \x2) everything works. The part I do not understand is that it works at the beginning for Y and V, but for X it doesn't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    % Define the pinhole coordinates in 3D space
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0.25,0);
    
    % Define the vector pointing from the pinhole to the sensor center
    \coordinate (V1) at (0,);
    \coordinate (V2) at (0.25,);
    \coordinate (V3) at (1,);
    \path let \p1=(V1), \p2=(V2), \p3=(V3) in coordinate (V) at (\x1, \x2, \x3);
    
    % Define the sensor center C using O and V
    \coordinate (C) at ($(O) + (V)$);
    
    % Define the sensor plane Y coordinate direction as (0, 1, 0)
    \coordinate (Y1) at (0,);
    \coordinate (Y2) at (1,); 
    \coordinate (Y3) at (0,);
    \path let \p1=(Y1), \p2=(Y2), \p3=(Y3) in coordinate (Y) at (\x1, \x2, \x3);
    
    % Define the sensor plane X coordinate direction as the cross product of V and Y by using the formula (V(2)*Y(3) - V(3)*Y(2), V(3)*Y(1) - V(1)*Y(3), V(1)*Y(2) - V(2)*Y(1))
    \path let \p1=(V1), \p2=(V2), \p3=(V3), \p4=(Y1), \p5=(Y2), \p6=(Y3), \n1={\x2*\x6 - \x3*\x5} in coordinate (X1) at (\n1,);
    \path let \p1=(V1), \p2=(V2), \p3=(V3), \p4=(Y1), \p5=(Y2), \p6=(Y3), \n1={\x3*\x4 - \x1*\x6} in coordinate (X2) at (\n1,);
    \path let \p1=(V1), \p2=(V2), \p3=(V3), \p4=(Y1), \p5=(Y2), \p6=(Y3), \n1={\x1*\x5 - \x2*\x4} in coordinate (X3) at (\n1,);
    
    % Define X as the coordinate of (X1, X2, X3)
    \path let \p1=(X1), \p2=(X2), \p3=(X3) in coordinate (X) at (\x1, \x2, \x3);        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For context: I decided on separating V and Y into three components, as I cannot use \z in let.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome. You can't use `\z` in `let` because there is not *z*. Every coordinate will be converted into a 2d represantation immediately. PGF/TikZ is, at its core, not 3d. (But it has support for it and there are packages like PGFPlots, [`tikz-3dplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot) and [`tikz-3dtools`](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools) that extend it somewhat. You might be interested in `tikz-3dtools` which seems to support 3d coordinates much better than core TikZ.

Comment: Yeah sorry, this is what I meant with cannot. My main problem was that I do not understand why the lines defining V and Y work, while X gives me this weird error. Thank you for the hint about tikz-3dtools, I will have a look!

Comment: `\x1` is `-809.55861pt` but this gets doubled (`scale=2`) and the result is outside of the range PGFMath/TeX uses. I'd also argue that `scale=2` is not a good idea in this kind of document, better to scale the *xyz*  coordinate system directly: `x=2cm, y=2cm, z=2cm` or just the part where the *V*s are defined (because after that you actually use the canvas coordinate system). But this is all moot if you can use `tikz-3dtools` which actually has support for doing arithmetics on 3d points (if you use the correct syntax).

Comment: Oh I see, thank you changing the units helped a lot!